How to compute the Hausdorff distance between two circles in $\mathbb R^2$
I’m working on computing the Hausdorff distance between two circles in $\mathbb R^2$ and need help with the specific calculation. The equations of the circles are given as:

$x^2+y^2=4$ (a circle with radius 2 centered at the origin).
$(x-3)^2+y^2-8y=0$ (a circle that I’ve rewritten as $(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 =16$, a circle with radius 4 centered at $(3, 4)$).

I’ve reviewed the definition of the Hausdorff distance, which measures the greatest distance between a point on one set and the closest point on the other set. I’m aware that the Hausdorff distance $d_H(A, B)$ between two sets $A$ and $B$ is defined as:
$$
d_H(A, B) = \max \left(\, \sup_{a \in A} \inf_{\lower0.55ex{b \in B}} \|a - b\|,\; \sup_{b \in B} \inf_{\lower0.5ex{a \in A}} \|b - a\| \right)
$$
But, I’m unsure how to apply this formula to the two circles in this case.
Any detailed steps or insights would be very helpful!

Consider the [both-sides infinite] line from a point on one circle (A) to the centre of the other (B).Consider where this line intersects B.

In this very special case, you might consider what the answer would be if the two circles were concentric. Then note that representative points providing that answer exist in every direction, including the direction you would need to translate a circle to make them concentric.

I would like to suggest a point of view which is very useful in this cases. The Hausdorff distance between sets $A$ and $B$, is also given by
$$ d_H(A,B) = \inf\{ \delta>0:  A\subseteq B^{(\delta)} \; \text{and} \; B\subseteq A^{(\delta)} \}, $$
where $A^{(\delta)}:= \cup_{a\in A} \{ y: d(x,y)\leq \delta \}$. Essentially is how much do you fatten $B$ by to contain $A$ and  vice versa. The fattening of a circle is either an annulus or a closed ball, when you fatten by more than the radius.
So the question reformulates what is the point in the origin centered circle farthest from (3,4), and what is that distance? And conversely what is
So the question reformulates what is the point in the origin centered at (3,4) farthest from (0,0), and at what distance?
For that reason compute the line between both centers and see where they intersect the circles. If I didn't make any mistake, the line should be $\frac{4}{3}x=y$, and the points are $(-\frac{6}{5}, -\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{27}{5},\frac{36}{5})$. The appropriate distances should be $4.56$ and $\frac{9\cdot 7}{5}$.
